# How to automatically disable 'Enchance pointer precision' mouse setting

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse, razer-mouse

I upgraded to Windows 8.1.

I'm using a Razer Taipan with Razer Synapse 2.

Every time I reboot, the `Enhance pointer precision` option is re-enabled, so I disable it every time, as it makes the mouse nigh-on unusable.

I've tried everything I can think of... deselecting that tick-box...

Comment: I'm having a similar issue where my "Adjust Visual Effects" are reset every time also.

Comment: "I upgraded to Windows 8.1" from which version?

Comment: Was it a clean fresh install on a formatted disk, or an actual upgrade?

Comment: This got resurrected! I've tried since on a clean install. The upgrade was from Windows 8. The problem is with Razer Synapse. I uninstalled it and have since had no issues. If I want to alter my DPI I have to install it, change it, and install it again though. Pretty annoying.